# Android lint: does not show message “Call requires API level 17 (current min is 14)”

Tags: android, lint

In some case, I found the android studio lint does not show the message “Call requires API level xxx (current min is xxx)”.

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_enter_leave_wifi);
    if(isDestroyed()){

    }
}

private class Test {
    Test(){
        if (isDestroyed()){

        }
    }
}
```

I found there is the error message in the isDestroyed() in the onCreate, but there is no such error tips in the constructor of Test

[image]

How to solve this issue?

UPDATE:

Current minSdkVersion is 14. That's why the isDestroyed(), which requires 17, in onCreate gives the error tip

Comment: What is your Min. API target?

Comment: that code is never called. therefore, the problem will never happen. -> try to instanciate `Test` to see if it changes the analyse.

Comment: I tried to create a new instance of Test, but still it doesn't show the error tip

Answer (score 0):

The functionality you want to perform requires higher API level access than your current minimum in which that functionality/access is not available.

In order to achieve that, simply change the API level of current minimum to the required one in app:gradle file. And then recompile the project.

Good Luck

Comment: I already set the minumum sdk to 14, that's why the isDestroyed() in onCreate gives the error tips. What I concern is the second isDestroy() not  shows the error tip

Comment: Are you getting any errors/issues except not showing hint ??? What's the required API level?